# Related Rates with negative rates of change

Tags: calculus, related-rates

If a car is moving towards an object and you get the rate of change to be -30 mph, I know that you don't say that the **speed** of the car is negative, it just means that the distance between the car and the object is decreasing. But, can you call that rate of change a vector? My question arises because if the car was speeding away from the object, the rate of change would be positive, so direction plays a role here.

Or does the sign of the rate of change just works as a description of increasing or decreasing?

Comment: Distance has no direction, so it's a scalar, but displacement includes a direction (towards/away), so it's a vector. Similarly, speed has no direction, so it's a scalar. But, velocity, the rate of change of displacement, does include a direction, so it's a vector. Your $-30$ mph is the velocity, while the speed is $|-30| = 30$ mph.

Comment: So, for example:

An airplane is flying 600 mph on a horizontal path that will take it directly over an observer. The airplane maintains a constant altitude of 7 miles. What is the rate of change of the distance between the observer and the airplane when =5 miles?

We are looking for the rate of change of the hypotenuse of the triangle. The answer is about -349 mph, but I would answer it as: the distance between the observer and the plane is decreasing at a rate of 349 mph at x = 5. But in this context, I do not see the rate of change between the observer and plane as a vector. Correct?

Comment: It's still a vector because there's a direction associated with it. The direction is "towards the observer," which doesn't seem like a particularly precise direction. But, we know enough to make that more precise if we wanted to. The angle of declination from the airplane to the observer (the direction of the hypotenuse) is $\tan ^{-1} \left( \frac{7}{5} \right)$ down from the horizontal - we can do the math to get the exact direction as an angle if we want.

Comment: Unless the motion is one-dimensional (along a line), it doesn't make sense to speak of a negative velocity either. For 1-D motion, the positive direction needs to be specified/defined, in which case yes, $-30$ mph is really a vector in $\mathbb R.$